# Recover multiple data from json

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse a json inside an HashMap to use the data inside my app.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
        JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject object1 = array1.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject object2 = object1.getJSONObject("job");

            JSONArray array2 = object2.getJSONArray("formations");

            if (array2.length() != 0) {
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < array2.length() - 1; i1++) {
                    JSONObject object3 = array2.getJSONObject(i1);
                    map.put("formation-created_at",

                }
            }
            map.put("testimony", object2.getString("testimony"));

            JSONArray array3 = object2.getJSONArray("themes");

            if (array3.length() != 0) {
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < array3.length() - 1; i2++) {
                    JSONObject object4 = array3.getJSONObject(i2);

                    map.put("themes-intro", object4.getString("intro"));
                }
            }

            JSONObject object5 = object2.getJSONObject("sector");

            map.put("sector-description", object5.getString("description"));
            list.add(map);
        }

        Log.d("testimony", list.get(1).get("testimony"));
        Log.d("themes-intro", list.get(1).get("themes-intro"));
```

I can recover the first object in the map with :

```
Log.d("testimony", list.get(1).get("testimony"));
```

But i cannot recover the one who is inside the loop :

```
Log.d("themes-intro", list.get(1).get("themes-intro"));
```

The logcat return the error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
```

I know that I should specify which "themes-intro" I want to call from the loop, but I cannot add a .get(x) to the expression.

Edit :

Here is the full json : http://komfushee.com/documents/ctai/jobs.json

And I've edited my code to give the full version of the code

Comment: can you post the JSON?

Comment: there is no println in your code, so i suggest you post a more complete example that actually fails.

Comment: typically, `list.get(1).get("formation-created_at")` is null, hence the crash. double check your json

Answer (score 0):

please use below code i think i hope it will be haplfull....

```
HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    if (array1.length() != 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object1 = array1.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject object2 = object1.getJSONObject("job");
            map1.put("testimony", object2.getString("testimony"));

        }
    }

    if (array2.length() != 0) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < array2.length() - 1; i1++) {
            JSONObject object3 = array2.getJSONObject(i1);
            map2.put("formation-created_at", object3.getString("created_at"));
        }

    }
```